# How to encrypt PHP with HTML file using phpBolt?

Tags: php, html, encryption

I'm trying to encrypt .php file using phpBolt. when only with PHP code then it's working, But if it's a mix of HTML then it is not working.

Encryption code:

```
<?php 

/**
 * src : source folder 
 * encrypted : Output folder
 */

$src      = 'src';
$php_blot_key = "kyc7fh";


/**
 * No need to edit following code 
 */

$excludes = array('vendor');

foreach($excludes as $key => $file){
    $excludes[ $key ] = $src.'/'.$file;
}

// $rec = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator( $src ));
$rec  = new DirectoryIterator($src);
$require_funcs = array('include_once', 'include', 'require', 'require_once'); 


foreach ($rec as $file) {

    if ($file->isDir()) {
        $newDir  = str_replace( 'src', 'encrypted', $file->getPath() );
        if( !is_dir( $newDir ) ) mkdir( $newDir );
        continue;
    };

    $filePath = $file->getPathname();

    if( pathinfo($filePath, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) != 'php'  ||
        in_array( $filePath, $excludes ) ) {  
        $newFile  = str_replace('src', 'encrypted', $filePath );
        copy( $filePath, $newFile );
        continue;
    }

    $contents = file_get_contents( $filePath );
    $preppand = '<?php define("PHP_BOLT_KEY", "kyc7fh"); bolt_decrypt( __FILE__ , PHP_BOLT_KEY); return 0;
    ##!!!##';
    $re = '/\<\?php/m';
    preg_match($re, $contents, $matches ); 
    if(!empty($matches[0]) ){
       $contents = preg_replace( $re, '', $contents );
       ##!!!##';
    }
    /*$cipher   = bolt_encrypt( "?> ".$contents, $php_blot_key );*/
    $cipher   = bolt_encrypt( $contents, $php_blot_key );
    $newFile  = str_replace('src', 'encrypted', $filePath );
    $fp = fopen( $newFile, 'w');
    fwrite($fp, $preppand.$cipher);
    fclose($fp);

    unset( $cipher );
    unset( $contents );
}

$out_str       = substr_replace($src, '', 0, 4);
$file_location = __DIR__."/encrypted/".$out_str;
echo "Successfully Encrypted... Please check in <b>" .$file_location."</a></b> folder.";
```

encryption not working in this .php file :

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>
            <?php 
                echo "Hello Sarbaz Ali !!!";
            ?>
        </h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

But when the file is look like this, then it will work:

```
<?php 
echo "<h1> Hello Sarbaz Ali !!! </h1>";
?>
```

Can I encrypt the above file (with HTML tags) using phpBolt?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that write your php code in seperate file , encrypt it with php_bolt and then include that file using PHP include function.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the [Laravel-Source-Encrypter](https://github.com/SiavashBamshadnia/Laravel-Source-Encrypter) package, which is based on phpBolt encoder:

> The blade files are not real PHP files. They mostly contain HTML and CSS codes.

Blade files are HTML code with PHP code, so there is no meaning in encrypting HTML code because there is no logic inside it.

phpBolt can only decrypt-and-execute php files (as a single indivisible step), it is not going to be possible to decrypt them again.

You can see also: [Can you tell me the how we can encrypt blade file?](https://github.com/SiavashBamshadnia/Laravel-Source-Encrypter/issues/25)

Comment: Recently, I worked on an example for encrypting a php project with a full-covered readme file. GitHub repo: https://github.com/ahmadmhdyones/protect-laravel.